# Difference of unifomization and local coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

What is the difference between the word *local coordinate system* and *unifomization* ?

I know the notion of local coordinate sytem, well. However, I cannot understand the unifomization.

Example.

> Let $C$ be a non-singular curve and denote by $t$ the local
>   *unifomization* varibale

In this context $C$ is not a disc.

Example

> Let $\Delta$ be a curve . We denote by $t$ the local *unifomization*
>   variable on $\Delta$.

In this context $C$ is  a disc.

Why the above two examples use the word   *unifomization* instead of *local coordinate*?

Answer (score 1):

It is the difference between local and global. The sentence

> Let $C$ be a non-singular curve and denote by $t\in \Delta$ the local *unifomization* variable

is very sloppy and one should refrain from using this language. It should be something like:

> Let $C$ be a connected Riemann surface of hyperbolic type (e.g. a compact Riemann surface of genus $\ge 2$). Let $f: \Delta\to C$ be the holomorphic universal covering map, where $\Delta=\{t\in {\mathbb C}: |t|<1\}$ is the unit disk. By abusing the terminology, we regard $t$ as the *uniformization variable* on $C$.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) for more details.

Edit. the answer also depends on the context. For instance, in Algebraic Geometry, **local uniformizer** is used for a generator of the local ring of an algebraic curve at the given point, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19308/what-is-a-local-parameter-in-algebraic-geometry). From the view point of complex analysis or differential geometry, such local uniformizer is the same thing as a local chart once restricted to a suitable open subset of the Riemann surface. In many cases, the word "local" is dropped.

Comment: I would like to point out that In algebraic geometry, the first is phrasing is not "very sloppy" - the local ring of any curve at a smooth closed point $x$ is a DVR and thus has a uniformizer $\pi$. Locally, translates of this function $\pi-\pi(x_0)$ for $x_0$ another closed point become uniformizers for the local rings at those points. This language is relatively standard, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19308/what-is-a-local-parameter-in-algebraic-geometry) for more discussion.

Comment: @KReiser: Oh, you are right, somehow I did not think about the AG aspect. I will modify my answer.